# Allow unauthorized/unregistered user to read data from firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I want to allow unauthorized or unregistered user to read some of my data from firebase that been write by authorized/registered user.

Here is my firebase database:

[image]

My rule for the firebase database is

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}
```

which only allowed authorized user to read the data.
I want to allow unauthorized user to able to read the AJK Information data. What firebase rule should I write to allow this to happen?

Comment: Make sure you are logined into firebase using firebaseAuth in android if you login the make sure you are makking request after login successfuly

Comment: https://medium.com/google-developers/controlling-data-access-using-firebase-auth-custom-claims-88b3c2c9352a how to control access to particular resources individually using Firebase Auth Custom Claims

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To give just the AJK Information node read access to everyone, you should call it out specifically in your rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null",
    "AJK Information": {
      ".read": true
    }
  }
}
```